# ios haptic feedback globally for all UIButtons

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uibutton

how can I apply haptic feedback throughout my app for every touchupinside event of every UIButton without writing code for each individual button? I have tried making a UIButton category and overriding `- (BOOL)pointInside:(CGPoint)point withEvent:(UIEvent *)event` but this messes up some of my UIButton actions, (i may have implemented it badly)

does anyone have any suggestions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Overriding in categories such kind of methods that mentioned @ChoungTran isn't such good idea. If you want to customize the default methods in a Category, it'd be better to do that in a [swizzled method](https://nshipster.com/method-swizzling/).

But, I'll prefer to make a custom class derived from UIButton, and implement that logic there and use that button everywhere where I need haptic.

---

From [Apple documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ObjectiveC/Chapters/ocCategories.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP30001163-CH20-SW1):

> Although the Objective-C language currently allows you to use a
>   category to override methods the class inherits, or even methods
>   declared in the class interface, you are strongly discouraged from
>   doing so. A category is not a substitute for a subclass. There are
>   several significant shortcomings to using a category to override
>   methods:
>
> When a category overrides an inherited method, the method in the
>   category can, as usual, invoke the inherited implementation via a
>   message to super. However, if a category overrides a method that
>   exists in the category's class, there is no way to invoke the original
>   implementation.
>
> A category cannot reliably override methods declared in another
>   category of the same class.
>
> This issue is of particular significance because many of the Cocoa
>   classes are implemented using categories. A framework-defined method
>   you try to override may itself have been implemented in a category,
>   and so which implementation takes precedence is not defined.
>
> The very presence of some category methods may cause behavior changes
>   across all frameworks. For example, if you override the
>   windowWillClose: delegate method in a category on NSObject, all window
>   delegates in your program then respond using the category method; the
>   behavior of all your instances of NSWindow may change. Categories you
>   add on a framework class may cause mysterious changes in behavior and
>   lead to crashes.

Comment: Besides, In your app you can have a case, where you don't want haptic (for example some system alerts which use UIButton subclasses, etc..)

Answer (score 1):

Try to use category with class UIButton. In UIButton-Extention register event forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside

```
#import "UIButton+Extention.h"

@implementation UIButton (Extention)

- (instancetype)init
{
    self = [super init];

    if (self)
    {
        [self addTarget:self action:@selector(customTouchUpInside:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    }
    return self;
}

-(void)awakeFromNib
{
    [super awakeFromNib];

    [self addTarget:self action:@selector(customTouchUpInside:)
                                 forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
}
- (void)customTouchUpInside:(UIButton *)sender
{
    //TODO:
    NSLog(@"Do something here...");
}
@end
```

Updated: Register event when UIButton created programmatically

Comment: Note that -awakeFromNib would be called only for buttons, loaded from nibs, but not for ones created programmatically.

Comment: @BorysVerebskyi yes, nibs or storyboard. If you want to create programmatically, try this

 - (instancetype)init
 {
     self = [super init];
     
     if (self)
     {
         [self addTarget:self action:@selector(customTouchUpInside:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
     }
     return self;
 }

Comment: It's possible to create a category that will handle all buttons. I think that instead of overriding -awakeFromNib one should override -viewWillMoveToSuperview. But I'm too lazy to check this now.